# Backing PDF files and SQL server DB

Tags: sql-server, windows, windows-server-2008, windows-server

I have my own Windows Server an Asp.Net application hosted live. The application allows users to upload CV PDF files and I have the DB also on that server. Which steps should I take to ensure that all data is there all the time even in case of hard drive failure?

I know RAID5 can be done but I only want to backup certain folders on my hard drive. I have heard of SQL server replication which would prevent the data loss in case of hard drive failure.

Which tactics are you using for this purpose on your server?

Thanks.

Comment: What are your recovery point objective (how long can you afford to lose data) and recovery time objective (how quickly do you need to get your data back in the event of a catastrophe?)

Comment: @billinkc: I need to get it within 2 days in case of catastrophe.

Comment: How much data can you stand to lose? 15 minutes, an hour, half a day, etc?

Comment: @billinkc: Within 2 days is fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server replication would only address if you are storing those PDFs inside SQL Server (as opposed to using the local file system and storing their location (C:\somefolder\cf\001.pdf). Replication will require another box which you don't specify whether you have.

As a first look, I'd try something like [Amazon Glacier](http://aws.amazon.com/glacier/). It's cheap and it's going to address more situations than replication alone will (oh your house burnt down and both servers are toast?) And the post that got me to thinking about Glacier but perhaps it's not going to be as applicable in this case [Long Term Backup Storage With Amazon Glacier](http://www.brentozar.com/archive/2012/11/long-term-backup-storage-with-amazon-glacier/).

Comment: Glacier won't give you any kind of real time read/write - it can take up to 6 hours to pull a document out of glacier and small transfers will cost a small fortune - often 20 - 30 times more than the cost of storing the data itself if you're dealing with a large number of small files.

Comment: @JeremiahPeschka You mean I actually have to read your blog posts and not just skim titles?

Comment: Nah, you don't have to. I just might "that guy" you on the internet, though :P